# text highlighting (select to copy) stopped working in the terminal

Tags: command-line, clipboard, text, copy, paste

I have a weird effect in one workstation: suddenly, the system does not allow me to copy text **from a terminal** to paste it somewhere else by simpling selecting it.

I can still paste into the terminal the text that I select in other windows. The problem is restricted to copying by selection from the terminal.

Also, I am aware of the <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> key shortcuts. They do work fine, and so does copying and pasting with right clicks of the mouse after selecting text and then clicking "Copy" or "Paste" in the menu. However, I want to recover the misteriously gone ability of copying text from the terminal by selecting it...

Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: That's odd. Presumably, you use the same action (middle click) to paste when it works, right? And does it happen with all terminals or only the default (gnome-terminal)? I assume it's `gnome-terminal`-specific, but try installing `xterm` (`sudo apt install xterm`) just to double check.

Comment: Have you looked in the profile settings of your terminal ? I believe there is a section on behaviour/gestures.

Comment: Hi Robert. Yes, I made sure that the "Copy selected text into clipboard" option was switched on in the Propfile preferences menu, but it didn't help.

Comment: I have the same issue, but also right-clicking and selecting Copy doesn't work anymore. A newly started konsole works. This is most certainly a bug, because it just stops working after a while - more or less at random moments.

Comment: It starts suddenly on my unbut 18.04 and it affects other applications as well, like the IDE I am using. There if I click anywhere, release and drag in the IDE it starts selecting text as if I was holding my left-button even tho it is released. My right click stopped working in the IDE also.

Comment: I wonder if my ubuntu gnome terminal is not related to using and pasting via CopyQ and sometimes using remote parsec client (even after turning it off) along which seems to affect clipboard functionality, however at the time of testing it was disconnected, and a new terminal console window works  as already previously written by Carlo, Ubuntu 20

Comment: Started happening in my Ubuntu 20.04 today. Does not work anymore in terminal or any other application. Select to copy not working, middle click mouse to paste also not working

Answer (score 0):

This might be a stretch but I have experienced something like this on my work laptop before. It tends to happen when I have many applications up and stacked on top of each other in the same window my terminal is. Even though the text is getting highlighted in the terminal, the click board doesn't end up with anything in it kinda like if one of the other windows was mysteriously between your mouse and the terminal window. What made it work for me is minimizing all the applications at once by doing the mouse shake. Sorry about the not so scientific answer.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me with Konsole as well.

Investigation of /var/log/syslog showed the following message each time I tried to copy:
"QXcbClipboard::setMimeData: Cannot set X11 selection owner"

Following up on that message, it seems the issue was reported/fixed by:
https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-65145
https://codereview.qt-project.org/c/qt/qtbase/+/254187

That issue matched my case, as my system had been up for 50 days before the issue started !

Looking at changelogs, that fix appears to be included in the 5.12.6 QT release.

Ubuntu 20.04.2 appears that it includes 5.12.8 currently, so should include the fix.

Answer (score 0):

Its now 2021 and this Konsole bug still exists, I'm on Debian 10, Konsole 18.04.0 build against KDE 5.54.0, Qt 5.11.3 + xcb.

You can temporarily work around it by giving your profile a new name, delete all other profiles and re-select 'Switch Profile' in the Konsole context menu, then select your newly saved profile.

However, it randomly comes back, also I have seen that it randomly creates new profiles (Profile 1, Profile 2, Profile 3)

From what I have observed, as long as you have 'Default Profile' as the name when you open Settings-> Edit Current Profile it doesn't persist options randomly.

Answer (score 0):

go to terminal settings and create new profile and try selecting text in it
maybe the profile did a setting that you don't know

or try changing your shell sometimes the problem is in the shell

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install -y zsh
sudo apt install -y fish
sudo chsh
# 'Write shell Name Here'
```

Perform these commands to change your shell